# Two parallel line segments intersection

Tags: geometry

I know there are many algorithms to verify whether two line segments are intersected.

The line segments I'm talking about are length line constructed by 2 end points.

But once they encountered parallel condition, they just tell the user a big "No" and
pretend there is no overlap, share end point, or end point collusion.

I know I can can calculate the distance between 2 lines segments.
If the distance is 0, check the end points located in the other line segments or not.
And this means I have to use a lot of if else and && || conditions.

This is not difficult, but my question is

**"Is there a trick( or mathematics) method to calculate this special parallel case?"**

**I hope this picture clarify my question

http://judark.myweb.hinet.net/parallel.JPG**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? By definition, parallel lines never intersect.

Comment: Parallel lines never intersect unless the distance is 0.
But since their distance is 0, they are overlaped.
However, my question is about the line segments.
The stretched lines are overlapped, but the line segments are remain unknown.
So I try to ask a solution to reveal the unkown.

Comment: Judarkness you probably need to refine your question a little bit.  What does it matter if they are line segments or not if we are checking for parallelism?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, given the formulas for both of the lines, test whether their slopes are equal.  If they are, the lines are parallel and never intersect.

If you have points on each of the lines, you can use the [slope formula](http://cs.selu.edu/~rbyrd/math/slope/).

If both are perpendicular to the x-axis, they will both have infinite slopes, but they will be parallel.  All points on each line will have equal x coordinates.

To deal with line segments, calculate the point of intersection, then determine if that point of intersection exists for both of the segments.

Comment: Oh my. I guess I'd better fill the character requirement. I was mistaken. =P

Comment: @Tyler: But I would add what my original answer says: I think determining if a given point is on both lines should be an easier way to distinguish the two cases than finding the distance bewteen two lines.

Comment: Make it simple, my line segments are lengthed lines, but not infinite straight lines. Excep the intersection or not, I have all other info like slope, distance, vector. That's for the other calcualtions :)

Comment: Your question is really confusing then.  If two line segments are parallel, they don't intersect.  Isn't that what you asked?  That's what I thought, since you wrote: "Is there a trick( or mathematics) method to calculate this special parallel case?"

Comment: @whirlwind he's talking line segments, not lines. The question is, for 2 (colinear) parallel line segments, how to determine if there is overlap?

Comment: I didn't see the picture... or the word "colinear."  His edit resolves that.

Comment: How many dimensions do you need?  For 2D and 3D it's possible to do this with a cross product formula and sorting.

Comment: oops. . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

I can't say there is a "trick" but there is indeed an efficient way of knowing if two collinear line segment intersect.

Let's assume we have two collinear line segments : [AB] and [CD]

### Translating coordinates to 1D

First of all, we need to translate the coordinates of the points into a 1D environnement, because it will be way easier to compare the positions of the points.

The process is rather straight forward : we will shave off from our coordinates the y and z values. It works because there is no two points on a line which have the same x value (as long as the line segment does not belong to a plane orthogonal to the x axis). But if the points all have the same x value, then we will instead take the y coordinate. And if the points all have the same y coordinates, we will account for the z coordinate. And if we arrived at that point, the points cannot all have the same z coordinate.

The method used to know if all points have the same x/y coordinate is to calculate the vector `AB`. If `AB.x` equals `0`, it means that we don't have to move on the x axis to get from point A to point B, thus the points A and B have the same x value, and so is it for the points C and D.

I am mostly talking about 3D here, but the point is the same for 2D, 4D, 5D...

The code would look like

```
if AB.x == 0
    if AB.y == 0
        A = A.z
        B = B.z
        C = C.z
        D = D.z
   else
        A = A.y
        B = B.y
        C = C.y
        D = D.y
else
    A = A.x
    B = B.x
    C = C.x
    D = D.x
```

### Detecting the collision

Detecting the collision is also quite straight forward in the end. There is exactly 52 different relative positions the points A, B, C and D can have (including 2 points having the exact same coordinate). Among these 52 positions, there are 44 that indicate there is a collision and only 8 that indicate the contrary. Thus the obvious solution is to only look for those 8 positions.

But we can reduce this number to 2. Indeed, if we consider that the coordinate of A and B, and C and D are in ascending order, there are only 13 different relative positions the four points could have (*see Notes section). And among these 13 positions, only 2 indicate that there isn't any collision. Those 2 positions are when D has a lower x value than A (`C-D A-B`) or when C has a greater x value than B (`A-B C-D`).

So after sorting the points A and B, and C and D, we would return `false` if `D < A or B < C` and `true` otherwise, which gives us `return not( D < A or B < C )` or in a more simplified way : `return A <= D and C <= B`

This final part of the algorithm should look like :

```
if A < B
    if C < D
        return A <= D and C <= B
    else
        return A <= C and D <= B
else
    if C < D
        return B <= D and C <= A
    else
        return B <= C and D <= A
```

### Notes

The 13 different positions A, B, C and D can have are :

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃
┃  AB        ┃  A B       ┃  A   B     ┃
┃━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃
┃  A    B    ┃  A      B  ┃    A B     ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃
┃    A  B    ┃    A    B  ┃     AB     ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃    C  D    ┃
┃     A B    ┃     A   B  ┃       A B  ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃    C  D    ┃            ┃            ┃
┃        AB  ┃            ┃            ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the case you're interested in is where the two line segments are parallel (as determined by checking the slope, as Whirlwind says), and you're trying to determine whether the two segments overlap.

Rather than worrying about the distance between the lines, I would think the easiest way to do that would to if either endpoint of one segment lies within the other:

```
if (segment_contains_point(segment_A, segment_B.start) || 
    segment_contains_point(segment_A, segment_B.end)) {
        // lines overlap
}
```

Comment: This is just what I want, I have my own segment_contains_points()(in other name)

But It's way too inefficient.

And I have to call it three times because segment B might be larger and contains the whole segment A.

And I want to know if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have two lines described by formulas `a.x + b.y + c = 0` and `d.x + e.y + f = 0`.  The two lines are parallel when `a = 0 and d = 0` or `b/a = e/d`.  Perhaps instead of doing the division just make sure that `b.d = a.e`.

Answer (score 0):

i found this (modified a little by me to suit)
it will return the intercetion x,y else if no intercetion found it will return -1,-1

```
    Public Function intercetion(ByVal ax As Integer, ByVal ay As Integer, ByVal bx As Integer, ByVal by As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer) As Point
    '//  Determines the intersection point of the line segment defined by points A and B
    '//  with the line segment defined by points C and D.
    '//
    '//  Returns YES if the intersection point was found, and stores that point in X,Y.
    '//  Returns NO if there is no determinable intersection point, in which case X,Y will
    '//  be unmodified.

    Dim distAB, theCos, theSin, newX, ABpos As Double

    '//  Fail if either line segment is zero-length.
    If ax = bx And ay = by Or cx = dx And cy = dy Then Return New Point(-1, -1)

    '//  Fail if the segments share an end-point.
    If ax = cx And ay = cy Or bx = cx And by = cy Or ax = dx And ay = dy Or bx = dx And by = dy Then Return New Point(-1, -1)

    '//  (1) Translate the system so that point A is on the origin.
    bx -= ax
    by -= ay
    cx -= ax
    cy -= ay
    dx -= ax
    dy -= ay

    '//  Discover the length of segment A-B.
    distAB = Math.Sqrt(bx * bx + by * by)

    '//  (2) Rotate the system so that point B is on the positive X axis.
    theCos = bx / distAB
    theSin = by / distAB
    newX = cx * theCos + cy * theSin
    cy = cy * theCos - cx * theSin
    cx = newX
    newX = dx * theCos + dy * theSin
    dy = dy * theCos - dx * theSin
    dx = newX

    '//  Fail if segment C-D doesn't cross line A-B.
    If cy < 0 And dy < 0 Or cy >= 0 And dy >= 0 Then Return New Point(-1, -1)

    '//  (3) Discover the position of the intersection point along line A-B.
    ABpos = dx + (cx - dx) * dy / (dy - cy)

    '//  Fail if segment C-D crosses line A-B outside of segment A-B.
    If ABpos < 0 Or ABpos > distAB Then Return New Point(-1, -1)

    '//  (4) Apply the discovered position to line A-B in the original coordinate system.
    '*X=Ax+ABpos*theCos
    '*Y=Ay+ABpos*theSin

    '//  Success.
    Return New Point(ax + ABpos * theCos, ay + ABpos * theSin)
End Function
```

[Origin](http://alienryderflex.com/intersect/)

Comment: This doesn't solve the question of determining if colinear line segments overlap—in fact in the comments to this code it specifically says it'll fail for colinear (and parallel) lines: // Fail if segment C-D doesn't cross line A-B

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem: The easiest way I have come up with just to check whether the lines overlap: 
Assuming the segments are colinear (parallel and have the same intersection with the x axis).
Take one point A from the longer Segment (A,B) as starting point. Now find the point among the other three points that has the minimal distance to point A (squared Distance is better, even manhattan-length might work too) measuring the distance in the direction of B. If the closest point to A is B, the lines do not intersect. If it belongs to the other segment they do.
Perhaps you have to check for special cases like zero length lines or identical lines but this should be easy.